# FFMPEG outputting a timelapse video without any frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, codec, image-editing

I'm new to FFMPEG but have created three timelapses on it (I forgot the commands I used to make them though).

I have ~400 images with consecutive numbering from `IMG_1744_EDITED.JPG`. I edited the RAW files in Lightroom and exported them to JPEGs with dimensions of `3416x5183`, and file sizes of ~12MB. I want to make a timelapse out of them, so I did:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -start_number 1744 -i IMG_%04d_EDITED.JPG -vcodec libx264 -preset veryslow timelapse.mkv
```

this runs without any error messages, but outputs an `.mkv` file that is just black when it runs.

Sensing it might be an issue with the file format, I tried an `.mp4` output instead. Again, same issue.

I tried decreasing the resolution of the files, so I resized them all down to `1080x1349` (different aspect ratio because I added white padding to the left and right) - which worked perfectly (files now ~150KB).

Tried the same command, again with both `.mkv` and `.mp4` formats but still gives the same error.

Where am I going wrong?

The best situation would be to use the `3416x5183` files by the way, and produce both an `.mkv` (I want quality over file size) and `.mp4` video.

Comment: How are you playing the videos?

Comment: @Gyan Windows' built-in player - do you think it's an issue with my video player?

Comment: Most likely. The original resolutionat 30 fps exceeds H264 level 5.2 limit and level 6+ are too new for players to accept for those players which vet streams for compliance. That could be it.  Of course, WMP has refused to play any H264 stream with width > 2048 for me.

Comment: Well I've tried with VLC - same issue. I'll look into the H.264 Level 5.2 limits. Thx :)

Comment: Can you share the log output of `ffmpeg -i IMG_%04d_EDITED.JPG` and `ffmpeg -i 1080x1349-image.jpg`?

Comment: @Gyan I don't have access to my PC right now - but after googling around I can probably say is definitely an issue with my fps/res. combination because H.264's largest supported res. is `4,096×2,160@60`, which is way too small. I can't find any media players that support Level 6 H.264 - so I'm guessing my only option is to use a different compression format such as H.265 or decrease the resolution. If I recall correctly the log output was normal though - ffmpeg ran through with no errors and created a file.

Comment: I can play a H264 video of that res in Potplayer, VLC and ffplay, of course.